# Grails audit logging plugin for mongodb is not working

Tags: mongodb, grails, audit-logging

I am using grails 2.2.3 , mongodb 1.3.3 the curd operation is working fine.

I want to log my curd operation

so i use  audit-logging plugin "audit-logging:1.0.0",it work fine with mysql-database but not with mongodb.It shows

```
Error 2014-05-05 15:45:04,117 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Cannot get property 'datastores' on null object

Message: Cannot get property 'datastores' on null object

   Line | Method
->>  90 | doCall   in AuditLoggingGrailsPlugin$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync

|   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask

|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker

|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

Any one came across this issue.

help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance. cheers..

Comment: Is this the very first error you see in the logs (or output)?

Comment: yes, runtime error occured

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your report the issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPAUDITLOGGING