# Grails Audit plugin not working with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, grails, grails-plugin

Grails [audit plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) is not working with the MongoDB

Even though it's mention in the documentation that it will work with mongoDB

Compatibility issues

Users of Grails 1.2.x and below should use version 0.5.3 of this plugin. Users of Grails 1.3.x and above should use version 0.5.5.3 of this plugin. If you use Grails >= 2.3 we recommend to use 1.0.0 or above.

**Starting with version 1.0.0, this plugin is ORM mapper agnostic, so you can use it with the ORM mapper of your choice (Hibernate3, Hibernate4, MongoDB, etc.).**

I have the following configuration setup

BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile ":mongodb:3.0.3"
compile ":audit-logging:1.0.5"
```

NOTE: not using any Hibernate plugin

Error I am getting on Starting the Application is:

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
2015-08-03 20:30:48,774 +0530 ERROR GrailsContextLoaderListener:213  - Error initializing the application: Cannot get property 'datastores' on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'datastores' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at AuditLoggingGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(AuditLoggingGrailsPlugin.groovy:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at AuditLoggingGrailsPlugin$_closure1.call(AuditLoggingGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:488)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doPostProcessing(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:176)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.performPostProcessing(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:240)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:35642', transport: 'socket'
```

I also Found a similar question which redirects to this link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470095/grails-audit-logging-plugin-for-mongodb-is-not-working](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPAUDITLOGGING)

Comment: This should have been fixed with version `1.0.6-SNAPSHOT`, can you give that a try?

Comment: Error initializing the application: No such property: config for class: org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore

Comment: Error has changed though.

Comment: if (!application.config.auditLog.disabled && !datastore.config.auditLog.disabled) { ... this line is triggering the error.

Comment: Can you raise an issue in github and refer this question in description? https://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/issues

Comment: So basically plugin is still broken ??

Comment: No, recently there was a fix for Mongo datastore. My assumption is that it might be affecting your use case. I believe the issue to look at is https://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/issues/91 which show cases the same issue as yours.

Comment: Can you suggest me any alternate solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with latest 1.0.6-SNAPSHOT version. See Issue https://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/issues/91